# @media screen and (min-width) does not work

Tags: html, css

I try to add margin to div when window is bigger than 1205px, but the problem is when the browser is bigger, the margin will not add to map-container not even when I use `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">`. Any suggestions how to fix or what I do wrong ?

```css
@media screen and (min-width: 1205px) {
 .map-container {
  margin-top: 71px !important;
 }
}
```

```html
<div class="map-container">
 <div id="map" style="width: 100%;height:400px">Map</div>
</div>
```

Comment: is `map-container` an element or is it a class/id? it would help if you post your html so we have a [mcve]

Comment: Yes it is class and I forget to add . before it, you help me

Comment: Please post your html code

Comment: It would be easier if you can post your code in https://codepen.io/pen/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `map-container {...}` bit is wrong.

If your map-container is an id (i.e. `<something id="map-container">`) change that to `#map-container {...}` and if it is a class (i.e. `<something class="map-cotainer">`) change it to .map-container {...} instead.

Did my answer solve your issue? Please make sure to mark it as accepted to help other people with the same problem.

Comment: <map-container> (as a custom element) is valid and complies with W3C

Comment: Yes it is class and I forget to add . before it.

Comment: Didn't know that, thanks, although without any HTML code I hope you can see why I made that mistake.

Comment: @Matthew Christopher Yes it is work but I need wait few minutes to mark it for right asnwer